# Varchar storage and performance

Tags: mysql, varchar

I have a simple query, It might be answered before but I didn't find the precise answer for the same.

My question is:

I created a table using JPA through entity. Now I shows string fields as `varchar(255)`. Now I'm wondering that what will happen when I'll save some data in that field of size let say 10? Will it save that data in 10 bytes or it will use 255 bytes?

Any clarification will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought in MySql up-to 255 chars with a varchar it is the number of characters you store plus 1 for length. So if you  put a value that's 10 characters long, that'll be 11 bytes on disk.

*UPDATE*
Found a link to the documentation to back that up. First table demonstrates the difference between char and varchar: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html

Answer (score 0):

- Don't lose sleep over the issue, but...
- `VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` needs a 2-byte length field, since it could up to 1020 bytes.
- Certain temp table operations expand the `VARCHAR` into `CHAR` during complex `SELECT` statements, thereby taking more space, albeit temporarily.
- Good practice is to use a reasonable max-length, but big enough for anything you might eventually put in it.